# Javascript dataTransfer and input type=file issue

Tags: javascript, html

As part of a piece of work I need to do I am trying to add in a javascript drag and drop feature. Normally with drag and drop on drop one passes the `event.dataTransfer.files` to an ajax call to an external file (like upload.php) to save the file. However in my case I am needing to integrate it with an existing form that has an `<input type="file">` field.

Is there a way to take the `event.dataTransfer.files` information when one drops a file in to a 'drop zone' and inject it into the `<input type="file">` field so that when the form is submitted the file is uploaded (e.g. mimic the click 'browse' on the file field and select a file)?

Comment: You cannot programmatically update the value of a file input field.  Is there any reason why you can't simply send the file and associated form fields via XHR (where supported)?

Comment: I think that is supported in HTML5 http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/

Comment: I suspected one couldn't populate a <input type="file"> field programmatically. Will have to rethink the approach to this. Cheers

Comment: I faced a similar issue and I just wanted to mention that in my particular case `event.dataTransfer.files` (from a dropzone) behaved the same as `event.target.files` (from a file input) -- so I was able to pass event.target.files into the same method & achieve the upload. May help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, input[type=file] is read-only for security reasons. I just solved a similar problem by converting the input[type=file] to an input[type=hidden] and setting the value as the base64 encoded URI of the image.

(Incidentally this works automatically with Paperclip https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/data_uri_adapter.rb )

Here's my jquery code:

```
$(function() {

  function renderPreviewImageFromFile(e,file) {
    file = file || $(this).prop('files')[0];
    if(file) {
      var img     = $(this).parents('li').find('img.preview');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        img.attr('src', e.target.result);
      }      
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      return img.attr('src');
    }
  }

  $("ul.images-list")
    .on('change','input.file',renderPreviewImageFromFile);

  jQuery.event.props.push("dataTransfer");
  $('.file-drop')
    .on('dragover dragenter', function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('hover');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }).on('dragleave dragexit', function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }).on('drop', function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('hover').find('span').remove();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // change input into hidden field
      file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
      input = $(this).parents('li').find('input.file');
      value = renderPreviewImageFromFile.apply(input, [null, file]);
      input.attr('type','hidden').val( value ).parents('div.input').hide();
    });

});
```